# JAVASCRIPT steps to setting up utterscroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have been trying to set  up utterscroll and i cant seem to be able to

there is no clear instruction, 
i put both files provide in order and i call the event but nothing 
https://github.com/debiki/utterscroll

i cant even get it to work on a jsfiddle

```
<script src='jquery-scrollable.js'></script>
<script src='debiki-utterscroll.js'></script>

if (!Modernizr.touch)  // if not a smartphone
  debiki.Utterscroll.enable({
      scrollstoppers: '.CodeMirror, .ui-resizable-handle' });
```

Comment: wow its been impossible setting this up damn

Comment: The developer tools are your friend - are those scripts actually loading? Any errors in the console?

Comment: yes @steveax i checked in the source file and nothing here is my source  https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B-C0T_-acxRqOFhzRWNzR2Y3VVk&usp=sharing im working on the demo.php

Comment: i mean i checked the source code on demo.php and each script displays its code in the source code, it just never works for me

Answer (score 0):

Now I've added an example HTML file that shows how you can enable Utterscroll on your page:

http://rawgit.com/debiki/utterscroll/master/utterscroll-example.html

(Linked from https://github.com/debiki/utterscroll)

What that page does, is it places this before `</body>`:

```
<script src='https://rawgithub.com/debiki/utterscroll/master/debiki-utterscroll.js'></script>
</body>
```

and this in the `<head>`:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($) {
      if (!Modernizr.touch) { // if not a smartphone
        debiki.Utterscroll.enable();
      }
    });
  </script>
```